# Problem enabling a NVIC IRQn channel in the STM32F407

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

I am trying to use the NVIC controller to see when the data is available from a peripheral. The peripheral is connected to an external interrupt line through a GPIO port pin. I have configured this pin to work as an external interrupt and from has an interrupt number equal to IRQn (as seen in the functions).

```
HAL_NVIC_SetPriorityGrouping(NVIC_PRIORITYGROUP_4); //This has all 4 bits as preemption priority bits
HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(IRQn, 0, 0);
HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(IRQn);
```

The problem lies when I am trying to use the function below

```
HAL_NVIC_GetPendingIRQ(IRQn)
```

My code will still run because when an interrupt is not active it is still in the pending state. I don't know if the problem may exist inside the processor and some configurations I am missing. Online I find that the previous lines are enough to implement the NVIC but it does not work.

PS: This is programmed in the C language and I am using the HAL driver macros and functions as you can see by the HAL- prefix. Additionally, when polling to this specific external interrupt line, it works fine
i.e.

```
__HAL_GPIO_EXTI_GET_IT();
```

Comment: `it does not work` means did you verify the actually values setting to Interrupt register ??

Comment: It's not working means, the ISR Handler is not triggered?

Comment: Thiru: Yes, I verified all needed registers were set when debugging. And the peripheral was also working .

Comment: A.R.C:  yes, that's why I meant kind of. I couldn't check the handler was actually triggered but I supposed that since it seemed that a communication between the NVIC and the external interrupt line.

Comment: But I managed to solve it. The lines I was missing was to enable all configurable interrupts and that the setting of the interrupt was after the setting of the GPIO port. Additionally I had to define what the IRQ handler for that external interrupt will do. THIS website helped me understand better.http://www.eng.auburn.edu/~nelson/courses/elec5260_6260/slides/ARM%20STM32F407%20Interrupts.pdf